# Deprecation of std::allocator<void>

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++17, std, allocator

Related: [Why do standard containers require allocator_type::value_type to be the element type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50245277/1348273)

It is said that the following has been deprecated since C++17:

```
template<>
struct allocator<void>;
```

I wonder whether it is deprecated because the primary template alone is now able to accommodate `allocator<void>`, or the use-case of `allocator<void>` is deprecated.

If latter, I wonder why. I think `allocator<void>` is useful in specifying an allocator not bound to a specific type (so just some schema/metadata).

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/L0IolOWBKPA there's a discussion here.

Comment: Trying to ping @NicolBolas who participated in the discussion, the question is rather interesting to me as well.

Comment: Related: [What is a void `std::allocator`? ie: `std::allocator<void>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67053471/what-is-a-void-stdallocator-ie-stdallocatorvoid).

Answer (score 5):

According to [p0174r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0174r0#2.4)

> Similarly, `std::allocator<void>` is defined so that various template
>   rebinding tricks could work in the original C++98 library, but it is
>   not an actual allocator, as it lacks both `allocate` and `deallocate`
>   member functions, which cannot be synthesized by default from
>   `allocator_traits`. That need went away with C++11 and the `void_pointer`
>   and `const_void_pointer` type aliases in allocator_traits. However, we
>   continue to specify it in order to avoid breaking old code that has
>   not yet been upgraded to support generic allocators, per C++11.

Answer (score 5):

It's not that `std::allocator<void>` is deprecated, just it isn't a explicit specialisation.

What it used to look like was something like:

```
template<class T>
struct allocator {
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef const T* const_pointer;
    // These would be an error if T is void, as you can't have a void reference
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef const T& const_reference;

    template<class U>
    struct rebind {
        typedef allocator<U> other;
    }

    // Along with other stuff, like size_type, difference_type, allocate, deallocate, etc.
}

template<>
struct allocator<void> {
    typedef void value_type;
    typedef void* pointer;
    typedef const void* const_pointer;

    template<class U>
    struct rebind {
        typdef allocator<U> other;
    }
    // That's it. Nothing else.
    // No error for having a void&, since there is no void&.
}
```

Now, since `std::allocator<T>::reference` and `std::allocator<T>::const_reference` have been deprecated, there doesn't need to be an explicit specialisation for `void`. You can just use `std::allocator<void>`, along with `std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<void>>::template rebind<U>` to get `std::allocator<U>`, you just can't instantiate `std::allocator<void>::allocates`.

For example:

```
template<class Alloc = std::allocator<void>>
class my_class;  // allowed

int main() {
    using void_allocator = std::allocator<void>;
    using void_allocator_traits = std::allocator_traits<void_allocator>;
    using char_allocator = void_allocator_traits::template rebind_alloc<char>;
    static_assert(std::is_same<char_allocator, std::allocator<char>>::value, "Always works");

    // This is allowed
    void_allocator alloc;

    // These are not. Taking the address of the function or calling it
    // implicitly instantiates it, which means that sizeof(void) has
    // to be evaluated, which is undefined.
    void* (void_allocator::* allocate_mfun)(std::size_t) = &void_allocator::allocate;
    void_allocator_traits::allocate(alloc, 1);  // calls:
    alloc.allocate(1);
}
```