# Why do standard containers require allocator_type::value_type to be the element type?

Tags: c++, containers, language-lawyer, std, allocator

Related: [Deprecation of std::allocator<void>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50244772/1348273).

The following description about template parameter `Allocator` is found for both [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) (emphasis mine):

> An allocator that is used to acquire/release memory and to
>   construct/destroy the elements in that memory. The type must meet the
>   requirements of Allocator. **The behavior is undefined if
>   `Allocator::value_type` is not the same as `T`**.

The last sentence does not make sense to me. If a specific `value_type` is required, couldn't it just do an allocator rebind?

Comment: I actually couldn't find this requirement in the standard. I am either missing it, or cpp reference here is not correct.

Comment: @SergeyA This is given indirectly in the "Allocator-aware container requirements" table in [container.requirements.general], assertion/note for the `allocator_type` expression.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, oh, general container requirements! Thanks.

Comment: Huh, one more crazy thing to add to the list about allocators I suppose. This is particularly weird since `std::list` is almost certainly rebinding to an internal node type

Answer (score 1):

The reason is mostly historical—rebinding was more complicated before C++11 added `allocator_traits`.  The [Networking TS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4656.pdf) defines a “proto-allocator” concept ([async.reqmts.proto.allocator]) where rebinding is always applied before any use, so it seems likely that the requirement will be relaxed someday.

Comment: I think the reason is _even more historical_. When STL was written, C++ probably didn't have template template class parameters. Otherwise, we could have the much more logical, `std::vector<T, std::allocator>` or `std::list<T, std::allocator>`, and it would be the class's responsibility to generate the type `std::allocator<T>` (or `std::allocator<TNode>`).